# Merge json list having same index in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following json data:

```
{
    "leadId": 0,

    "nationalAvg": {
        "2007": 822.0,
        "2008": 830.0,
        "2009": 880.0,
        "2010": 909.0,
        "2011": 979.0,            
    },
    "stateAvg": {
        "2007": 1023.0,
        "2008": 1026.0,
        "2009": 1035.0,
        "2010": 1050.0,
        "2011": 1072.0,
        "2012": 1150.0,
    },
    "zipCodeAvg": {
        "2007": 1050.98,
        "2008": 1054.06,
        "2009": 1063.29,
        "2010": 1078.69,
        "2011": 1101.27,
        "2012": 1181.49,
        "2013": 1297.64,
        "2014": 1349.99,
    }
}
```

**I want to merge nationalAvg, stateAvg, zipCodeAvg together to have a result like:**

```
["2007":  822.0,      1023.0,   1050.98]
["2008":  830.0,      1026.0,   1054.06]
["2009":  880.0,      1035.0,   1063.29]
["2010":  909.0,      1050.0,   1078.69]
["2011":  null,       1072.0,   1101.27]
["2012":  null,      1150.0,    1181.49]
["2013":  null,      null,      1297.64]
["2014":  null,      null,      1349.99]
```

I want to show this data on google line chart.

Comment: So what have you tried? And is the output correct?

Comment: That output is not valid JavaScript... You'd need something like `{ "2007": [822.0, 1023.0, 1050.98], "2008": [830.0, 1026.0, 1054.06], ...}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
    const  list = {
        "leadId": 0,

        "nationalAvg": {
            "2007": 822.0,
            "2008": 830.0,
            "2009": 880.0,
            "2010": 909.0,
            "2011": 979.0,            
        },
        "stateAvg": {
            "2007": 1023.0,
            "2008": 1026.0,
            "2009": 1035.0,
            "2010": 1050.0,
            "2011": 1072.0,
            "2012": 1150.0,
        },
        "zipCodeAvg": {
            "2007": 1050.98,
            "2008": 1054.06,
            "2009": 1063.29,
            "2010": 1078.69,
            "2011": 1101.27,
            "2012": 1181.49,
            "2013": 1297.64,
            "2014": 1349.99,
        }
    }


    let keys = ['nationalAvg', 'stateAvg', 'zipCodeAvg'];

    let obj =keys.reduce((acc, c, i) => {
     Object.entries(list[c]).map(( o ) => { 
      acc[o[0]] = (acc[o[0]] || Array.from({length: keys.length}).fill(null));
      acc[o[0]][i] = (o[1]);
        });
     return acc;
    }, {});

// Format 1
console.log(obj);

const result = Object.entries(obj).map(o=> [ o[0], ...o[1]]);
//Format 2
console.log(result)
```

Comment: This is a perfect solution

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```js
const data = {
    "leadId": 0,

    "nationalAvg": {
        "2007": 822.0,
        "2008": 830.0,
        "2009": 880.0,
        "2010": 909.0,
        "2011": 979.0,            
    },
    "stateAvg": {
        "2007": 1023.0,
        "2008": 1026.0,
        "2009": 1035.0,
        "2010": 1050.0,
        "2011": 1072.0,
        "2012": 1150.0,
    },
    "zipCodeAvg": {
        "2007": 1050.98,
        "2008": 1054.06,
        "2009": 1063.29,
        "2010": 1078.69,
        "2011": 1101.27,
        "2012": 1181.49,
        "2013": 1297.64,
        "2014": 1349.99,
    }
}

const keys = ['nationalAvg', 'stateAvg', 'zipCodeAvg'];

const years = keys
  .reduce((a, k) => [...a, ...Object.keys(data[k])], [])
  .filter((v, i, arr) => arr.indexOf(v) === i)
  .sort();


const result = years.map((year) => 
  [year, ...keys.reduce((a, k) => [...a, data[k][year]], [])]
);

console.log(result);
```

How this works: it first creates an array of all the years (all the keys of the three objects), filters out all the duplicates from that array and then map it to add the value for those years (those properties) from the three objects.

Comment: `[...a, ...Object.keys(data[k])]` is slower, less readable, more characters, and susceptible to stack overflow on large data compared to `a.concat(Object.keys(data[k]))`, similar story with `[...a, data[k][year]]`